# To earn a direct title for coming first in an official FIDE tournament, do we include players who already have that title?

Tags: titles

I'm intending to play in the Oceania Zonal tournament ([brochure](https://www.fide.com/images/stories/FIDE_Calendar_2018/2019_Oceania_Zonal_entry_form.pdf)) and direct titles will be awarded in this tournament.  I'm interested in the WIM title.  The [FIDE handbook](http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=199&view=article) says in regards to the WIM title:

> **Sub-Continental Individual**
> 1st equal – title;
> Silver & Bronze – norm
>
> 1st equal = best 3 players after tiebreak;

The current list of entries are [here](http://www.chesschat.org/showthread.php?17258-2019-Oceania-Zonal-Guam-17-24-Feb-2019/page3) and it includes WGM [Julia Ryjanova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_Ryjanova) ([2308](https://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=4127714)) and IM [Irina Berezina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irina_Berezina) ([2109](https://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=3201937)) who are much stronger than me.  Both players, however, already have titles higher than the WIM title, and I would like to know if they "count" for awarding direct titles.  Do I need to score at least as much as them?

**Question**: To earn a direct title for coming first in an official FIDE tournament, do we include players who already have that title?

Layla Timergazi ([FIDE](https://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=4303733)) received the WIM title at the last Oceania Zonal, but she was outright first ([crosstable](http://www.newzealandchess.co.nz/Vega2017/wwwOceaniaZonalWomens/crosstablescore.html)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, we include all the players who participated in the event. If you finish second after WGM Ryjanova, you will receive a norm but not the title. If you finish fourth, you receive neither, regardless of who is on the podium. If the level of the field is high with a lot of tilted players participating, it often occurs that no 'special' title is awarded at the end of the tournament.

For instance, the World Junior champion is awarded with a grandmaster title. This year, the [tournament](http://wjcc2018.tsf.org.tr/en/component/turnuva/?task=fileview&kid=975) was won by Iran's Parham Maghsoodloo, who was already a GM. The first non-GM in the tournament, IM Sergei Lobanov, did not receive that title instead (he 'only' got a GM-norm for his third place).

Comment: I think I answered a different question :)